# How can I fix IAP code after upgrading to Swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swift2

I get an error saying "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SKProductsRequest' with an argument list of type'(productsIdentifier: Set)' and I'm still trying to learn the syntax changes. Any help?

```
 if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {

            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.organization.appname.iap")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifier: productID as Set<NSObject>)

            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast it as `Set<String>` and it will work fine.

Here is new code:

```
let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.organization.appname.iap")
let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: (productID as! Set<String>))
```

Syntax is changed for 2.0:

```
// request information about products for your application
@available(iOS 3.0, *)
public class SKProductsRequest : SKRequest {

    // Set of string product identifiers
    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    public init(productIdentifiers: Set<String>)  //Set<NSObject> will not work anymore

    @available(iOS 3.0, *)
    unowned(unsafe) public var delegate: SKProductsRequestDelegate?
}
```

Comment: How to change productRequest function? now response is a String and it does not have the object invalidProductIdentifiers